# Delete directory content from Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I use this Gradle configuration to copy generated asciidoc files.

But I need to delete old outdated files also.

```
task copyDocument(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn bootJar

    from file("build/docs/asciidoc/")
    into file("src/main/resources/static/")
}
```

How I can delete the content of directory `src/main/resources/static/` before I paste the new generated files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task copyDocument(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn bootJar

    from file("build/docs/asciidoc/")
    into file("src/main/resources/static/")
    doFirst {
        delete "build/folder"
    }
}
```